# How to get the object when called the List<type>.any()

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of the class 'Cpu',the cpu class is like as that:

```
public class Cpu
{

     public string SerialNum{get;set;}
     public string BandName{get;set;}
     public string Status{get;set;}
     ...
}
```

I have a list of Cpus,List cpulist;
and I want to sort out the cpu with the unhealty status.So I used the code like the code below

```
foreach(Cpu cpu in cpulist) {
      if (cpu.status!='healthy') {
            saveinfo(cpu's information);
      }
}
```

but I know a easily way to do this like the code below:

```
 if (cpulist.Any(cpu => cpu.Status != "Healthy")) {
          //I can find whather a cpu is unhealty
          //but I want to save the unhealty cpu's information,I don't know 
          //which cpu has issues,and **my questions is how to find the specific cpu 
          //with unhealty status**
 }
```

What I mean is how I can get the cpu object when I called the List.Any.

Comment: `cpulist.Where(cpu => cpu.Status != "Healthy")`

Comment: @JLRishe Oh! Thanks for pointing that out. I was looking at the code that uses `Any`, and thought OP wanted _any_ unhealthy CPU. Their lack of plurals also made me think there is only one. Now that I reread the question and saw what they are doing with the foreach loop, I am a bit confused as to what OP wants.

Comment: @Sweeper I agree it's confusing, but it seems their objective is to log information about all their bad CPUs (which is what the `foreach` loop is doing), but they discovered LINQ and are looking to take advantage of it.

Comment: Thank you very much ,and I found this code can be used to get the list of unhealthy cpus.

Comment: `cpulist.Where(cpu => !cpu.Status.Equals("Healthy", StringComparison.InvariantCulture)).Select(bad => new Action(()=> saveinfo(bad))).AsParallel().ForAll(a => a.Invoke());`

Answer (score 0):

The `Any` method returns true if at least one item in the collection matches your condition, else false.  So it does not return any items itself.

In your case, you wish to execute an action upon the items which match, so `Any` is not the right approach.

You can instead use either `FindAll` or `Where`

`FindAll` is an extension method on `List<T>` and it return a new `List<T>` of all matches items.  You can use it like this:

```
foreach (var foundItem in cpulist.FindAll(delegate (Cpu obj) { return !obj.Column.Status("Healthly"); }))
{
  ... 
}
```

Or you can use the Linq `Where` method.
This executes on any type that implements `IEnumerable` and so it returns an instance of `IEnumerable`.

You can use it like this.

```
foreach (var foundItem in cpulist.Where(cpu => !cpu.Status.Equals("Healthy")))
{
    ...
}
```